# How download file from GET XMLHttpRequest response on IE?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest GET request for file download:

```
var filename = 'data.zip';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET',  "/solfwk/srp/exportImportService/export", true);
request.responseType = 'blob';
request.setRequestHeader("ALFSSOAuthNToken", token);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.onload = function() {
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
   link.download = filename;
   if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0) {
      link.text = "Start...";                                        
      $('#messageExport').empty().append(link);
   } else {
      link.click();
   }
   $.unblockUI();
};
request.send();
```

For non-IE browsers `link.click()` works, but for IE it does not. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `for IE it does not` is not helpful, what happens, any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find such solution using msSaveBlob or msSaveOrOpenBlob functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

for IE use:

```
 var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

To determine if XmlHttpRequest is available in browser, use following code:

```
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
```